# choosing the sensor for sensing moving automobile

Tags: networking, sensors

I want to detect the moving automobile in the path and i don't know use what kind of sensors,please help me.

Comment: A GPS system maybe? But, above all, what this have to do with programming??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If precision is not an issue you could just use a semi-decent webcam like the PS3 Eye and OpenCV for visual recognition, if it is an issue then something laser based perhaps.

If you want more specific answer please write some details to your question, exactly what kind of problem you are facing!

Answer (score 0):

there you can find one of the most affordable laser sensors that can be used in robotic applications

- http://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/
- http://www.intorobotics.com/high-precision-laser-sensors-in-robotics/